# How to access a controller(Branding.php) with .php extension like http://localhost/myproject/branding.php in code igniter using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I want to access one of my controller with it's. PHP extension like http://localhost/myproject/branding.php

In the above scenario, myproject is my project name, branding is my controller name.
I could able to access http://localhost/myproject/branding but while I am adding a .PHP extension in front of my controller name, its throwing error(Page not found.).

How to fix the issue by using .htaccess.

Framework- codeigniter

I am using below code in .htaccess to hide index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using Codeigniter-3 framework, there's no need to achieve that with .htaccess. You can set to add an url suffix in your `application/config/config.php` file:

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.php';
```

> This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by
>   CodeIgniter.

e.g.: a link created with the url-helper function

```
<?= anchor('branding');?>
```

will add the suffix `.php` automatically and address your controller `branding` and it's `index()` function.